# AutoCompleteTextView dropdown can't change dropdown list elevation and padding

Tags: android, view, adapter, autocompletetextview

im using AutoCompleteTextView inside a TextInputLayout and populating it with help of ArrayAdapter.

```
    val view = TextInputLayout(
        ContextThemeWrapper(
            this,
            R.style.AppTheme_TextInput_Dropdown
        )
    )
    
    val autoCompleteTextView = AutoCompleteTextView(
        ContextThemeWrapper(
            view.context,
            R.style.AppTheme_AutoCompleteEditText
        )
     <setting some parameters here>

    val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
        arrayOf("Temporary", "Mocked", "Data", "Some other data", "Testing123"),
    )

    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
    view.addView(autoCompleteTextView)
    return view
```

The effect looks like this

[image]

but i want to change the padding and elevation on the dropDown list so it looks like this

[image]

Haven't found any useful method/parameter that could do it strainght forward. Is there some easy way to do it or maybe changing ArrayAdapter to some other (ex. SpinnerAdapter) adapter could do the job ?

Edit: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try below:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView;

public class AutoCompleteDropDownExample extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = new AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    autoCompleteTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
    autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, new String[]{"Temporary", "Mocked", "Data", "Some other data", "Testing123"});
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

    setContentView(autoCompleteTextView);
}
```

- You are not setting layout params for `AutoCompleteTextView`
- `setDropDownWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);` will do the trick.

Comment: Im setting layout params, just didnt mention it, considered it redundant information sorry.
Increased with view.setMaxWidth() so pretty muhc like you did, but the main problem is the top padding (too much free space over first element). Still looking for a solution for that.

Comment: Can you share whole Activity/Fragment code along with xml if any?

Comment: Activity is 360 lines long. There is no XML. Evereytinh is made dynamically. I posted important fragment of code. Beside the code i posted theere are some paraneters being set like size, color etc  but it doesnt matter.

Comment: Can you try disable the hint? using `setHintEnabled(false);` on AutoCompleteTextView. IF that doesn't work, then please share your onCreate() method.

Comment: All works fine, just want to get rid of these paddings i posted in Edit. That's someting with adapter or xml of the item adapter is using.

Answer (score 0):

Made it look better by adding my own implementation of XML that im loading in activity

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

then in Activity

```
val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.dictionary_list_item,
            arrayOf("Temporary", "Mocked", "Data", "Some other data", "Testing123"),
        )
```

- changed width like in previous answer/comments.

At the end of the day i still don't know how to change the dropList container padding, but it looks good enough now [image]